# How to version control .idea folder independently of project with Mercurial?

Tags: intellij-idea, mercurial, phpstorm

PhpStorm (and other IntelliJ IDEs) create a `.idea` project folder which stores settings in XML format. JetBrains recommends version-controlling these files so that they can be shared amongst the team.

My team tried this in the past but ran into trouble because we're constantly switching between branches which really messes with our settings/IDE.

Is there a way, in Mercurial, to version these files independently of our main project so that when we switch branches the `.idea` files are left as-is?

Comment: I would in fact not recommend version controlling anything under `.idea`.

Comment: @vikingsteve Why's that? We wanted to share our dev database connection settings so that we don't have to teach everyone how to configure it.

Comment: I would ignore them in your code repos and have a separate "config" repo that everyone has access to and you pull and copy to the IDE Environment.

Comment: @Edward You would ask everyone to copy-paste each time? I was hoping for something a bit more automated.

Comment: I would, but in our case the changes occur infrequently and the files are used to quickly setup a new project (which is also infrequent). What is the volume and/or frequency of changes in your setup?

Comment: Well I wouldn't think the right place to share your database connection settings would be under `.idea`. The resources folder sounds a more logical place, perhaps in another module / project. I'm not sure how it works in PhP world but in java world we try to keep our projects under source control as IDE-agnostic, and use a build tool like maven or gradle to manage the structure.

Comment: @Edward The settings don't change very frequently, but it's difficult to coordinate everyone. If I were to say "update your project settings people!" I'd get questions like "how do I do that?" or half of them would just ignore me. The simpler I can make it, the better.

Comment: @vikingsteve This isn't some custom file I'm talking about. It's `.idea/dataSources.xml` which is created by the IDE. The DB connection settings that the app uses are stored elsewhere. We don't really care about being IDE-agnostic because everyone *is* using the same IDE; this isn't an open-source project. And even if someone wanted to use something else, the `.idea` folder wouldn't hurt them. We're using `gulp` for build automation, so this is really just a convenience thing.

Comment: Ok. Having put that detail in your question would have helped ;) Did you know that DataSources can be 'IDE' scoped, and not just 'Project' - I haven't used this feature, but I wonder would that be a suitable set up for you?

Comment: @vikingsteve No, I didn't know you could change the scope, but that's not particularly relevant. Project-scoping is fine, we just need a good way to share the file without running into version conflicts.

Comment: Okay. I would be tempted to do this via environment variables or via symlinks if possible, but yole has posted how to have multiple source roots in your project. I have found this feature a little problematic with v13 (had to keep reselecting the second source root in branches when project reloaded), but maybe it works better in v14

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do so. Add the .idea directory to .hgignore, then create a separate Mercurial repository in the .idea directory. Under Settings | Version Control, make sure that you have both your project directory and the .idea directory as VCS roots, with Mercurial selected as the VCS.